# How to use a nested request with insights in the Facebook API

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to include insights in a single call to Facebook ads API using Ruby. I researched this and got the following call:

```
params = {
    'time_range': {
        'since': '2019-08-01',
        'until': '2019-08-31',
    }
}

ad_account.campaigns(
    fields: [
        'adsets{
            id,
            insights{spend, impressions, clicks, ctr, cpc},
            adcreatives{id, object_story_spec, image_url, object_type}
        }'
    ],
    params: params
).to_json
```

My response:

```
[
    {
        "adsets"=>{
            "data"=>[
                {
                    "id"=>"xxxxxxxxx",
                    "adcreatives"=>{
                        "data"=>
                            [
                                {
                                    "id"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                    "object_story_spec"=>{
                                        ...
                                    },
                                    "image_url"=> "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/xxxxxx",
                                    "object_type"=>"SHARE"
                                }
                            ],
                            "paging"=>{
                                "cursors"=>{
                                    "before"=>"xxxxxx",
                                    "after"=>"xxxxxxx"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                ...
```

So by levels, I am able to get all the `campaigns`, then the `adsets` inside them, and the `adcreatives` inside the `adsets`, but not the `insights`.

Am I doing something wrong? Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

So, surprisingly, Facebook DOES return insights with my call. Sometimes. No explanation why, but I tried with two accounts and got on one account insights and the other not.
Maybe it has something to do with the insights returned with this call have a shorter lifespan, so you can't get insights for older ads. Not sure. Not going to read through the million of pages.

My solution, for whoever is interested.
I made a call to adaccount insights directly, and specified the level as 'ad' so ir will return insights for all the account ads. I also requested the 'ad_id'. Later I was able to match the results returned with this call to the previous call I mentioned by comparing the ad ID, and merge the results.

```
ad_account.insights(
    fields: ['ad_id', 'spend', 'impressions', 'clicks', 'ctr', 'cpc'], 
    level: 'ad',
    time_range: {
        since: date_since,
        until: date_until
    }
).to_json
```